# NullPointerException when using intent extra

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception

So yesterday i did some coding where i get data from my SQL database to display into a dialogue box and from there i have a button that takes the user to an update page where the user can update the data, so i used `intent.putExtra` to get an auto fill method for the update `edit box`. When i ran the code yesterday everything worked perfectly but today when i ran it i get the following error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: Calculator.curtainclub, PID: 18730
                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{Calculator.curtainclub/com.digitalninja.mohammed.curtainclub.Products.UpdateDelete.Upvalence}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2957)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                        at com.digitalninja.mohammed.curtainclub.Products.UpdateDelete.Upvalence.onCreate(Upvalence.java:71)
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7174)
                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1220)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2910)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

My activity where the dialogue box is on:

```
 list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {



        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            /** To change selected state view */
            view.setSelected(true);
            HashMap<String, Object> obj = (HashMap<String, Object>) ADAhere.getItem(position);
             String SlectedName = (String) obj.get("NAME");
              String SlectedPrice = (String) obj.get("PRICE");
               String SlectedSize = (String) obj.get("SIZE");
              String SlectedRange = (String) obj.get("RANGE");
              String SlectedSupp = (String) obj.get("SUPPLIER");
           final String SelectID = (String) obj.get("ID");

          final  String SlectedName1 = (String) obj.get("NAME");
            final  String SlectedPrice1 = (String) obj.get("PRICE");
            final   String SlectedSize1 = (String) obj.get("SIZE");
            final  String SlectedRange1 = (String) obj.get("RANGE");
            final  String SlectedSupp1 = (String) obj.get("SUPPLIER");
           // Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), SlectedName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
            dialog.getWindow();
            //dialog.setTitle("Confirm your Vote");
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.diaglog);

            final TextView VName = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Name);
            final TextView VRange = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Range);
            final TextView VSUPPLIER = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Supplier);
            final TextView VSIZE = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Size);
            final TextView VPrice = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Price);


            VName.setText(SlectedName);
            VRange.setText(SlectedRange);
            VSUPPLIER.setText(SlectedSupp);
            VSIZE.setText(SlectedSize);
            VPrice.setText(SlectedPrice);
            dialog.show();
            Button cancelBtn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel_btn);
            cancelBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            Button UpdateBtn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.updateval);
            UpdateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),Upvalence.class);
                    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                    extras.putString("ID", SelectID);
                   extras.putString("name",SlectedName1);
                    extras.putString("Range",SlectedRange1);
                    extras.putString("Supplier",SlectedSupp1);
                    extras.putString("Size",SlectedSize1);
                    extras.putString("Price",SlectedPrice1);
                    i.putExtras(extras);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
            Button deleteBtn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);
            deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),del.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });


            dialog.show();

        }
    });
```

and my update activity where i call the `intent`:

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_upvalence);

    search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    name1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    name2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
    name3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);
    name4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText8);
    name5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText9);


    btnsearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btnUpdate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel_btn);
    btnDel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
  if  (extras!= null) {

      String ID = extras.getString("ID");
      String name = extras.getString("name");
      String range = extras.getString("Range");
      String supp = extras.getString("Supplier");
      String size = extras.getString("Size");
      String price = extras.getString("Price");


      search.setText(ID);
      name1.setText(name);
      name2.setText(range);
      name3.setText(supp);
      name4.setText(size);
      name5.setText(price);

  }

    btnsearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            CheckLogin checkLogin = new CheckLogin();
            checkLogin.execute("");
        }
    });

    btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CheckLogins checkLogins = new CheckLogins();
            checkLogins.execute("");
        }
    });

    btnDel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CheckLoginsss checkLoginsss = new CheckLoginsss();
            checkLoginsss.execute("");
        }
    });


}
```

Comment: One or more of your buttons (`btnsearch`, `btnUpdate`, `btnDelete`) is `null`. Check your IDs against your `layout/activity_upvalence.xml` file. Whichever button is on line 71.

Comment: @MichaelDodd fixed thank you